# Deleting multiple or single items from list box

Tags: vb.net

I have created a list box and at the moment I am trying to make it such that you can delete one item or multiple items using this code:

```
Private Sub Delbtn_Click(ByVal sender As Object, 
        ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Delbtn.Click
    lstCountries.Items.Remove(lstCountries.SelectedItem)
    lstCountries.Items.Remove(lstCountries.SelectedItems)

End Sub
```

However when using this I am not able to delete more than one selection at a time. What is the best way to make it so that I can delete one or more than one selection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure there are some things selected:

```
If lstCountries.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then

    ' MUST loop backwards thru collections when removing
    ' or you will remove the wrong things, miss stuff and
    ' run out early
    For n As Integer = lstCountries.SelectedItems.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        ' remove the current selected item from items
        lstCountries.Items.Remove(lstCountries.SelectedItems(n))
    Next n
End if
```

There is also a `SelectedIndicies` Collection which would return a collection of integers of the items.  If you iterate that, use `.RemoveAt()` but you still need to loop backwards.

Comment: Can you please explain what  'For n As Integer = lstCountries.SelectedItems.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1' and 'Next n' mean regarding this bit of code

Comment: @ Plutonix: let me know which type of text box you are using? that allows selection of multiple lines at a time?

Comment: @SujithKarivelil he has a listbox: `I have created a list box...`  (also the title)

Comment: my question is that is it allows to select multiple lines at a time?

Comment: I am able to select multiple lines but cannot delete multiple lines @SujithKarivelil

Comment: we are getting **way** off track.  this question involves a ListBox (not TextBox) and deleting selected Items (not lines).  If there is another question lurking, it should be a new question. (But a multi-line textbox will allow you to select lines)

Comment: @Plutonix the code has worked but I still don't get why you need the '1 To 0 step -1' part

Comment: that determines the loop; it means start at the number of selected items (`lstCountries.SelectedItems.Count - 1`); go thru them backwards (`Step -1`) one by one until you get to Zero.  Collections and such start at index 0, so the number of items is always `.Count - 1`.

Comment: Ok, I almost get it, but what does the term index mean in this language, and also isn't lstCountries.SelectedItems.Count the number of items, what is the purpose of the '- 1' afterwards?

Comment: -1 is because VB uses a zero based array so `0 to count -1` accounts for this.

Comment: So what would happen if I removed - 1 To 0 Step -1, can you please try to explain as simply as possible as I am just starting out

Comment: I gave you a [link to The Definitive Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z06z1kb.aspx) for this; take a look at it - each word and term is defined with some examples.  The code says *start at the last item and go to the first item, -1 item (step) at a time, and do the following:...*

Comment: I have read it and now mostly understand how the loop works but the only thing I am unsure of now is why you need to use ' lstCountries.SelectedItems.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1' instead of ' lstCountries.SelectedItems.Count To 0 Step -1'

Comment: from comment #9 (and @OneFineDay's comment): *Collections and such start at index [element] 0, so the **number** of items is always* `.Count - 1`.  Sort of the same way that this is the 21st century, but the year is one less 2014.  Take the -1 off of Count and you'll get an error

Comment: when you say that the collection starts at index 0 do you mean that when I have 1 item in the collection at the beginning the index is 0 not 1? And also can you give me an exact definition of the term index in this language because I am unable to find one online

Comment: Bingo! item #1 is in Slot/Element/Index/Place/Location 0; item #2 is in Slot/Element/Index/Place/Location 1. so the actual **count** such as for your loop is always 1 less than reported.